# Using knife search node to query packages with special characters in the name

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have a set of nodes that have different versions of the JDK installed.  With ohai, they display as follows:

jdk:
     arch:        x86_64
     epoch:       2000
     installdate: 1515713671
     release:     fcs
     version:     1.7.0_161
   jdk1.7:
     arch:        x86_64
     epoch:       2000
     installdate: 1518121328
     release:     fcs
     version:     1.7.0_171
   jdk1.8:
     arch:        x86_64
     epoch:       2000
     installdate: 1518120665
     release:     fcs
     version:     1.8.0_162

If I run "knife search node myname123 -a package.jdk", it returns the information for the package named "jdk".  If I run the same command with jdk1.7 or jdk1.8 nothing is returned even though the packages are there.  I tried escaping the "." with a "\" character even though period isn't listed as a special character.  That doesn't work either.  Is there a special way to search when the package has a period in the name?

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: Ultimately, I'd like to generate a list of all the nodes that have jdk1.8 that's not version 1.8.0_162.

Comment: Probably use `knife exec` for that'.